# Fill remaining space in react-virtualized Grid if total columns width is less than Grid width

Tags: react-virtualized

I use the Grid component with alternate rows background color.

In my application,  I can dynamically select which columns to display. If the total width of columns exceeds the grid's width, no problem. but if the total width is less than grid's width, I would like to fill the remaining empty space with the same background color as my cells. I don't want to change my columns' width to fit Grid's width.
Is there a easy way to do that?

I try to use prop cellRangeRenderer (as mentionned in the doc https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Grid.md#cellrangerenderer) but it seems to not solve my requirement.
Do I have to fork the defaultCellRangeRenderer function?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ5j4.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to fill the remaining space with the alternating colors (not entirely clear from your question) then you have two options.

For both options, you will need to detect when the width of your visible columns is less than the width of the `Grid`. (You didn't share your source code so I'm not going to make suggestions about exactly how to do this. It should be simple enough though!)

### Option 1: `cellRangeRenderer`

Fork the [default `cellRangeRenderer`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/Grid/defaultCellRangeRenderer.js). When your `Grid` has too few columns to fill it, either render an empty div on the right for each row (to fill up the remaining width) *or* override the `style` prop for the right-most cell in each row to make it fill the remaining width.

### Option 2: `columnWidth` function

Use a `columnWidth` function (which it appears you're already doing, based on your screenshot). When your `Grid` has too few columns to fill it, just return a different size for the right-most visible column (such that it fills the remaining space).

Note that you'll need to let `Grid` know when the width of a given column changes. You can do this by calling `gridRef.recomputeGridSize({ columnIndex: indexOfRightMostColumn })`.

Comment: Option 1 works great, just add also containerStyle={{ overflow: 'visible' }} as Grid property. Many thanks for taking the time to respond to my question.

Comment: @bvaughn, that is not a solution, ER should be like default table component doing that, filling empty space for each column